# To increment slider value by 1 by clicking the button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a slider when i clicked on the button the slider value is incremented  by one can any one help me.

Comment: Can you elaborate, the question is very brief? Are you using a `UISlider`? What have you tried already?

Comment: yes i am using the uislider when i clicked any of the button on the screen its value should increment by one

Comment: If you got the answer, kindly inform me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an outlet for the slider. And whenever you click the button, get the slider value, add 1 to it, and update the slider by outlet.

EDIT:

.H file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate


- (IBAction)incSlider:(id)sender {
    [_slider setIntValue:[_slider intValue]+1];

}
@end
```

.M file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate


- (IBAction)incSlider:(id)sender {
    [_slider setIntValue:[_slider intValue]+1];

}
@end
```

.xib's Screen shot
[image]

Comment: can you give me an example sir

Comment: here _slider is the outlet for slider, and increaseSlider is the action linked to the Command Button.

Comment: if you have some minimum or maximum range for the slider, and if you have float value, all required changes you can do quite easily... and if this solves your answer, do voteup and accept :)

Comment: Here the project: check and revert me .  http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/view.php?id=5245431&da=y

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using `[setValue: animated:]`  method of UISlider. You can set the slider using this method. Get a sample project shared on Github [Here](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCFineTuneSlider).

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the maximum value of slider greater than **1**.

Use:

```
float sliderValue = yourSliderOutlet.value;
[yourSliderOutlet setValue:sliderValue animated:YES];
```